# Classe Vector e números aleatórios em C++

Tags: c++, vector

A função só me devolve o endereço de memória, como faço pra que ela me retorne o conteúdo e não o endereço de memória?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>  ///  por causa de srand()
#include <stdlib.h>   // para poder gerar os pesos aleatorios ou pra poder usar o rand()
#include <vector>   /// vector que armazenara os meus neuroneos
#include <deque>
#include <iomanip>   // por causa do setw()

int* pes;

void funcaoGerarPesos(){   /// sempre por referencia

    int colunas = 10;

    /// lembre-se que o numero de pesos é sempre igual ao tamanho de exemplo de treinamento
    for (j = 0; j < colunas; ++j)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));     //// responsavel pela geracao automatica

        peso_aleatorio = (rand() % 6) + 1;    //// armazenar o valor gerado na variavel valor_treinamento

        pes = &peso_aleatorio;    //// o meu ponteiro apontara para o valor contido na variavel peso_aleatorio

        vector_pesos.push_back(pes);    //// pegar todos os valores gerados e colocar no vector de pesos
    }

    //// percorrer com o while
    it = vector_pesos.begin();

    while(it != vector_pesos.end()){

        cout << *it << endl;
        it++;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    funcaoGerarPesos();
}
```

Comment: Ola,a funcao so me devolve o endereco de memoria, como faco pra que ela me retorna o conteudo e nao o endereco de memoria, agradeceria se alguem pudesse ajudar, qualquer ajuda sera bem vindo, obrigado desde ja

Comment: Por favor, edite a sua pergunta para incluir nela essa explicação que você forneceu em comentário. Aproveite pra incluir também outras coisas que faltam, como por exemplo: (1) onde está declarada a sua variável `vector_pesos`? (2) por que você está adicionando no vetor um ponteiro e não o valor diretamente? (3) por que você não fez a sua função retornar diretamente um `vector<float>` ao invés de `void`?

Answer (score -1):

Respondendo a última pergunta feita nos comentários (Já que você já encontrou o problema).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        // O int e o ponteiro para int precisam ser redeclarados e redefinidos a cada iteração.
        int r = (rand() % 6) + 1;
        int *p;
        p = &r;
        v.push_back(*p);
    }
    std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin();
    while(it != v.end())
    {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
        it++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Como pode ver em meu exemplo, para que os números aleatórios não se repitam, é necessário redeclarar e redefinir o int e o ponteiro para int dentro do escopo do *for-loop*.

Vale lembrar que se seu compilador comporta o standard de 2011 do C++, você pode iterar sobre o loop de maneira muito mais simples:

```
for (auto e : v)
{
    std::cout << e << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: O problema nao é esse, essa funcao eu chamo dentro da minha funcao main, so que ele nao da erro, apenas retorna a posicao de memoria, e nao é isso que eu quero, eu quero o valor para cada posicao, mas obrigado

Comment: Qual função só retorna o "endereço de memória"? Não está evidente na sua questão. Eu testei aqui e funciona perfeitamente. Preciso de mais detalhes. Onde esse ponteiro foi declarado? Edite a questão pra adicionar os detalhes.

Comment: vou colocar o codigo completo entao

Comment: desculpe mas é que ficou uma bagunca, mas é esta mesma

Comment: Eu testei todo o código e ele funciona perfeitamente rs.. Os números aleatórios são armazenados no vector, e são "printados" com o std::cout. Não há endereço.

Comment: acho que ja encontrei a solucao, apenas troquei o tipo que o meu vetor recebia de int* para int e tm no caso do iterator

Comment: é que estou no ubuntu, se calhar é por isso, mas sinceramente nao sei se foi por isso, mas obrigado

Comment: mas como faco pra que o meu vetor nao gere numeros repetidos

Comment: Editei a minha resposta e respondi a sua última pergunta (Se resolver o seu problema, não esquece de aceitar a minha resposta como correta rsrsrs..).

Comment: nao tem problema